# Aikaike Information Criterion for model with fixed parameter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, aic, poisson-process

I am trying to fit an inhomogenious, reinforced Poisson process to time series data using maximum likelihood estimation. The inhomogenious rate is
$$ \lambda = \alpha \cdot f(t,\theta) \cdot (m +n).$$
where n is the number of observed events until time t, f is an aging (decaying) function and m,$\alpha$ and $\theta$ are parameters.
The likelihood is thus:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} (\alpha,\theta) = & \alpha^N \prod_{n=1}^N (m + n -1) f(t_n;\theta) \\
                & e^{-\alpha [(m+N)F(T;\theta)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}F(t_n;\theta)]}.
\end{align}$$

where $F(t;\theta) = \int_0 f(t;\theta)dt$.
The rate of the Poisson process depends on some parameter m that I am not optimizing (because MLE does not converge or give sensible results). However I am optimizing the other parameters $\alpha$ and $ \theta$, which works fine.
My main question is: Can I still use the Aikaike information criterion to compare model fits with different m?
A 2. question is : If I fit data to several timeseries independently, the log Likelihood of a model for the combined data should just be the sum of the individual log likelihoods (since the likelihood is the product). Would the combined AIC then just be the sum of the individual AICs?